# how to emulate a reverse/inverse counting mutex using only binary, counting, and recursive mutexes?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, mutex, reverse, counting

I'm not sure if reverse/inverse counting mutex is the name of the synchronization primitive I'm looking for, and search results are vague. What I need is the ability for a thread that wants to write to an object to be able to "lock" said object such that it waits for all existing readers of that object to finish doing so, but where no new thread/task can attempt to aquire any access to that object (neither read nor write), until the thread that wants to write finishes doing so and "unlocks" that object.

The question is how to design a class that behaves as such a synchronization primitive using only preexisting binary/counting/recursive semaphores.

Using a standard counting semaphore isn't suitable, since that only limits the max number of tasks that would be able to access the object simultaneously. But it doesn't restrict/enforce that they may only read, nor would they notifiy the thread that wants to write that they have finished, nor would it prevent any other threads in the meanwhile starting to read.

I need some kind of "counting" semaphore that is not bounded from above, but on which "register_read" or "lock_for_read" can be called (which keeps count how many simultaneous readers there are), but on which a task can call "lock_for_write", and then blocks until the count reaches 0, and after "lock_for_write" is called, any new calls to "lock_for_read" would have to block until the writing thread calls "unlock_from_write".

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock (also known as a "shared mutex")

Comment: yes thx! That not only told me what I was looking for, it also gave me the solution on how to implement it.